# npm ERR! arg Argument starts with non-ascii dash, this is probably invalid: [ '- g', 'appium' ]

Tags: node.js, npm

when i try to Installing Appium 
Open Command Prompt/Terminal and type the following command to install Appium:

**npm install –g appium**

**showing**

npm ERR! arg Argument starts with non-ascii dash, this is probably invalid: [ '-
g', 'appium' ]
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "-g": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIC
omponent encodes.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-08-23T07_34_08_
495Z-debug.log

NB:- Node.js v8.11.4 and npm 5.6.0

Answer (score 32):

I guess your **–g** is not a valid character. I also guess you are copy pasting the below command from somewhere,

> **npm install –g appium**

Please try entering the same command manually in your CMD prompt/console as below,

```
npm install -g appium
```

Comment: Thanks. I have resolved the issue when Manually typed the command.

On Windows CMD I was facing the same issue and because I have copied the command from a text file when typed the command manually, it worked well.

So when copying the command from some text file and adding that in Windows CMD, it is more commonly faced issue.

Comment: it was useful for me. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. I have saved the installation instructions on a word document and the Word's '-' is not the right character. Replace the '-' in the command line and should be fixed.